# Error "The given object ID is not that of a menu item" on menu with 40+ items

Tags: menus, errors

When ever I try to add menu items past about 40 I get an error "The given object ID is not that of a menu item" and many of my menu items will disappear from the menu at random.

The site I am working on has approx 65 pages in total but I am unable to get them all in because of this.

I am referring to the new WordPress menu management interface

Comment: Every item being added is either a normal page or a custom link, but no custom post types or taxonomies

Comment: Looks like it was a PHP memory limit that was causing the problem.Anyone else notice this?

Comment: Guys any one got a solution for this?

Comment: I have had the same issue. 40+ nav items in custom menu. only custom and pages. I already had 128M allocated; I changed that to 12800 to see if it would work still getting error. I am thinking I will just go in and manually update the mySQL database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found was to get in touch with my webhost and have them up the PHP memory limit on my account from 64MB to 128MB. The problem went away after that.

Answer (score 0):

Access your c-panel and site files then go to `wp-config.php` file and input the following line of code

```
/** Memory Limit */
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '96M');
```

Worked for me.